# Parser for chrome logs

Tags: chrome, python, logs

I'm looking for a script library for parsing Chrome/Chromium logs (one that look like `[22656:22656:1219/111826:VERBOSE1:plugin_service_impl.cc(251)] Watching for changes in: /usr/lib64/firefox/plugins`)

must be open-sourced (under whatever license it is), preferably python but any scripting language works for me as well.

Just like with any logging parsing it looks pretty straightforward but there are actually a lot of subtle issues to take into consideration. I'd hate to write it by myself

Answer (score 1):

You can try a [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash), an open source server-side data processing pipeline that can transport and process your logs, events, or other data. It has many [plugins](https://github.com/logstash-plugins), or you can write your own specifically for parsing Chrome/Chromium logs.

Check out the code at [GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/logstash).

---

For commercial solution, try [Splunk Enterprise](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/download/splunk-enterprise.html) (it has a  free trial). Checkout the [Splunk questions at Stack Overflow](https://github.com/logstash-plugins) to check for features that you may looking for.